# Who executes first in ASP.Net MVC Pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

My understanding of how the requests being processed in IIS 7.0 is as follows:

1. When the requests come inside IIS, `URLRoutingModule` processes it.
2. If `ÙRLRoutingModule` finds an extensionless URL (that is within the `RouteTable`) then it maps to corresponding controller.

However, I could not find answers to the following questions.

1. Previously, I have studied that `aspnet_isapi.dll` handles all `ASP.NET` related activities. So, in the HTTP Pipeline, which gets executed first ?
   [`URLRoutingModule or ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL`]
2. And Is `ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL` a `HTTP Handler` or a `ISAPI Extension`?

(I have read that `http handler` can be implemented by deriving from `IHttpHandler` whereas to write an `isapi extension` we need unmanaged code in C/C++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the HTTP Pipeline, which gets executed first ? [URLRoutingModule or ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL]

`ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL` gets executed first.  It transfers control to the managed ASP.NET runtime and invokes `URLRoutingModule` as necessary

> Is ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL a HTTP Handler or a ISAPI Extension?

It is an ISAPI Extension:

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524980(v=vs.90).aspx):

> ASP.NET functionality is contained in an ISAPI dll called Aspnet_isapi.dll.

HTTP Handlers are *managed* handlers that are invoked by the ASP.NET runtime.

From [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx):

> An ASP.NET HTTP handler is the process (frequently referred to as the "endpoint") that runs in response to a request made **to an ASP.NET Web application**.

Comment: @D Stanley: But wait. `ÀSPNET_ISAPI.dll` seems to handle a request and generate response. So, it follows the same definition of a `HTTP Handler` and why it is not called a `HTTP Handler` ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. I assume by "HTTP Handler" you mean a _managed_ HTTP handler. Those are invoked by the ASP.NET runtime, which is invoked by `ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL`, which is invoked by IIS.

Comment: Great. But this mean, that `.ASPX` pages are rendered fast than a MVC page if the former is processed first (by ASPNET_ISAPI.dll in the pipeline) ?

Comment: I believe `ASPX` requests still go through the routing module, but they are processed directly rather than decoding the URL into a controller and action.  So it may render _slightly_ sooner than an equivalent MVC page but it should be imperceptible.  I certainly wouldn't use that as a reason to use ASPX instead of MVC if that's where you're going.

Answer (score 4):

ASPNET_ISAPI.DLL is an ISAPI extension. These extensions are components (DLL, scripts, executables) that are registered in IIS. Each extension is registered to handle particular requests, since IIS itself handles very few of those. For instance, the name extension is registered to handle all requests identified as ASP.NET related.

ISAPI filters are DLLs that are used to add some behavior into the way IIS manages requests. These are listening to all incoming requests until they find one that they are able to process.

Notice that two concepts above are defined for IIS. HttpModules and HttpHandlers are different.

HttpModules and HttpHandlers are purely ASP.NET objects, so all things related to them happens after IIS handled request to ASP.NET pipeline. However their roles within ASP.NET resemble those in IIS - handlers handle particular requests, and modules intercept all requests and process some specified in their configuration.

URLRoutingModule is a standard HttpModule, soit intercepts the request handled over to ASP.NET and, if any of the routes registered in it matches the request, triggers the corresponding HttpHandler. Default handler for ASp.NET MVC is MvcRouteHandler, which then triggers the controller-related activities withing MVC.

Some links for further reading:

- [MVC request life cycle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/10/03/understanding-of-mvc-page-life-cycle.aspx)
- [ASP.NET in IIS overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524980%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [HttpModules explained](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178468.aspx)
- [ISAPI filters explained](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Explanation of routing in MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. So, `ISAPI Extensions` are very similar to `HTTP Handlers` & `ISAPI Filters` are similar to `Http Modules` except that the former is unmanaged. Is my understanding correct, Andrei ?

Comment: Right, although the other significant difference is that ISAPI* exists on IIS level, and HttpModule/handler is ASP.NET level only. Former comes into play first

Comment: Oh okay. So, first ASPNET_ISAPI called first and then if `.aspx` is not found, then it goes to `URLRoutingModule` ?

Comment: URLRoutingModule is a module, it intercepts all requests to asp.net, no matter if .aspx presents. However, if the route is not registered with any mvc application hosted in iis, this module is not going to pass execution to any of those, and will let the request follow standard ASP.NET pipeline. See link 5 in the answer where this is explained in greater details